# Dataflow Streaming using Python, MatchContinuously not working as expected

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried using a dataflow python library, for reading a data in streaming fashion from a bucket, using this link which was made available recently.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=matchall#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchContinuously

Here is the code snippet that I am using, to poll the bucket at regular intervals.

```
(pipeline
         | 'Match Files' >> fileio.MatchContinuously(file_pattern="gs://xyz/abc/*.txt", interval=10.0, has_deduplication=True)
         | 'Read Matches' >> fileio.ReadMatches()
......
```

This code is failing after waiting for a short while. Can someone help as of what I am missing ? Here's the stacktrace.

```
<PCollection[Read Matches/ParDo(_ReadMatchesFn).None] at 0x7fad0ccb7e80>
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 586, in __exit__
    self.result = self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 565, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 131, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 195, in run_pipeline
    self._latest_run_result = self.run_via_runner_api(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 206, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 384, in run_stages
    stage_results = self._run_stage(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 663, in _run_stage
    assert (runner_execution_context.watermark_manager.get_stage_node(
AssertionError: wrong timestamp for StageNode<inputs=['ref_PCollection_PCollection_3_split'],side_inputs=[].
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be failing in `Read Matches/ParDo(_ReadMatchesFn)` not in `MatchContinuously`, by checking the log.

This is probably due to you using `DirectRunner`, if i am not mistaken, StatefulDoFns are yet not fully supported in it [(matrix)](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/). `RemoveDuplicates` is a StatefulDoFn.

I tested your code in Dataflow and it works fine with no issues (both 2.32 and 2.33).

```
(p | MatchContinuously(f"gs://{bucket}/match/*", interval=10.0, has_deduplication=True)
   | ReadMatches()
)
```

Also, you don't really need `ReadMatches`, you can do this to read the text files. Maybe you can test this out and see if it works in DirectRunner

```
(p | MatchContinuously(f"gs://{bucket}/match/*", interval=10.0, has_deduplication=True)
   | Map(lambda x: x.path)
   | ReadAllFromText()
   | Map(lambda x: logging.info(x))
)
```

Both of them work fine in Dataflow.